# n-Queens Problem - Swift playground performance vs C#

Tags: c#, swift, swift-playground

Hi created this short C# code that searches for the first solution to the [8-Queens Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), but generalized to n. It uses backtracking algorithm.

```
static bool PlaceNextQueens(List<(int row, int col)> placedQueens)
{
    foreach (var pos in new GetValidPositions(placedQueens))
    {
        placedQueens.Add(pos);

        if (placedQueens.Count == ChessboardSize || PlaceNextQueens(placedQueens))
            return true;

        placedQueens.RemoveAt(placedQueens.Count - 1);
    }
    return false;
}

static IEnumerable<(int row, int col)> GetValidPositions(List<(int row, int col)> placedQueens)
{
    int row = placedQueens.Any() ? placedQueens.Last().row + 1 : 0;

    for (int col = 0; col < ChessboardSize; ++col)
    {
        if (!placedQueens.Any(q => col == q.col || Math.Abs(col - q.col) == row - q.row))
        {
            yield return (row, col);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, this runs in 40 ms for `ChessboardSize = 16` in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac, debug mode.

I'm re-approaching Swift, after some years, so I decided to port it just for the sake of exercise.
First problem I encountered is that Swift is missing something like `yield return`, so you must instead implement an iterator and take care of the state machine behind it.

This is the result:

```
func PlaceNextQueens(placedQueens: inout [(row:Int, col:Int)]) -> Bool {
    for pos in ValidPositionsSequence(chessboardSize: chessboardSize, placedQueens: placedQueens) {
        placedQueens.append(pos)

        if placedQueens.count == chessboardSize || PlaceNextQueens(placedQueens: &placedQueens) {
            return true
        }

        placedQueens.remove(at: placedQueens.count - 1)
    }
    return false
}

struct ValidPositionsSequence: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    let chessboardSize:Int
    let placedQueens:[(row:Int, col:Int)]
    let row: Int
    var col: Int = -1

    init (chessboardSize:Int, placedQueens:[(row:Int, col:Int)]) {
        self.chessboardSize = chessboardSize
        self.placedQueens = placedQueens
        self.row = !placedQueens.isEmpty ? placedQueens.last!.row + 1 : 0
    }

    mutating func next() -> (row:Int, col:Int)? {
        while true {
            self.col += 1
            if self.col == chessboardSize {
                return nil
            }
            if !placedQueens.contains(where: { self.col == $0.col || abs(self.col - $0.col) == self.row - $0.row }) // Don't need Abs() for row because it's always greater than $0.row
            {
                return (self.row, self.col)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that this is really slow, and completely unusable for `ChessboardSize >= 16`.

I know playground is probably not the best option to benchmark an algorithm, but the difference is astonishing.

Am I doing something bad? Or it is just the playground environment? Didn't try with release code so far.

Oh, and just for completeness, I also wrote a C# version with iterator, and it runs at the same speed of the `yield return` one.

Comment: “Swift playground performance vs C#” … “I know playground is probably not the best option to benchmark an algorithm” … You are correct: Playgrounds are entirely useless for benchmarks against other environments.

Comment: The playgrounds are hooking into literally every line of your code and generating counts, previews, and other such things. They're entirely contrary to what you're trying to do. Make this a standalone Swift program, and run it in release mode.

Comment: Ok, when compiled to release code, it over-performs .NET by ~5 times (understandable since .NET runs just-in-time compiled code)

Comment: Not as a critique, but this looks like a very literal translation from C#. Can't imagine anyone implementing it using `inout` and `Sequence` in Swift. It's not wrong, just not the way of thinking I guess. 
Also you can use things like `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` to take advantage of multi-threading.

Comment: Yeah, implementing it as multi-threaded would have been the next experiment. The `inout` is just because Swift collections are ValueTypes, and I need to pass it on for editing, this is a key feature for recursive functions. What should I do instead? And what is it strange with `Sequence`? It is just a lazy generator, a protocol thought just to do this kind of things.

Comment: By the way, I see `inout` quite used throughout the official documentation...

Comment: I'd just have `placedQueens` as a property of the object, instead of passing it back and forth. Like I said, nothing wrong with it, just unusual. Also `(row:Int, col:Int)` is asking to be `typealias`

Comment: In order to have `placedQueens` as a property, I would have had to create a struct or a class and instantiate it just to do a mere algorithm processing. C# or Swift, I find it not to be the best approach for these kind of things. In my opinion, passing things back and forth is absolutely normal for recursive functions. For `typealias` you are absolutely right, just something I need to get used to.